# Python: strptime() formatting

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, date-formatting, strptime

I'm using CPython.
This is the code:

```
import datetime
userBirthday = print("Enter your birthday(DD/MM/YYYY): ")
compBirthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userBirthday, "%d/%b/%Y")
```

I get this error message:

```
ValueError: time data '13/12/2001' does not match format '%d/%b%Y'
```

Comment: `%b` is for abbreviations like "Jun", "Apr". Read the docs, it's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted this instead:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(userBirthday, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Where m stands for "month".

Also, checkout `dateutil.parser.parse`, which can recognise a wide variety of formats.

Comment: Thank you sir! You are a life saver. When I started learning Python 3, %b was for month because %m was reservated for minutes. Thanks again!

Comment: I will accept your answe tomorrow because I have to wait 6 minutes and it's very late in my country.

Comment: @Alkemyk: `%b` means the same thing in Python 3 -- [month abbr., not number](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Minutes is `%M` (uppercase), `%m` (lowercase) is always month number.